# Hierarchical abstraction in c++

Tags: c++, abstraction, class-instance-variables

I have following abstraction in my code:

```
class A{};

class B: public A{};

class C: public B{};
```

Now when I declare an instance of class C every thing is OK. The problem is when I declare class C in a function (with new) an return it as a pointer. I don't get any error but it seems that the object doesn't carry the characteristics of class A. Is it possible to do this in a function?

Comment: Can you post the code of your function?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “carry the characteristics”? Showing some code to explain the problem always helps a lot. Please edit the question and clarify a bit

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Please post your code. You are probably doing something wrong and Without seeing the code one can only guess.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please provide the code you are have right now, otherwise we could not help you.

Comment: So you have `C* f() { return new C; }`, and the returned object has lost some of its "characteristics"? How do you know?

Comment: I have another class like: Class D and in this class I have a function like C* f() { return new C; }. The problem is that in runtime, the the variables don't become updated and valued correctly.

Comment: As others have requested, please edit your question to show the relevant code -- preferably a [mcve].

Comment: What you described in text, can be written as C++ code. Add a `main()` and, may be, some helpful `std::cout` statements to illustrate at run-time what happens (and what happens not) and you get a [mcve].

Comment: "it seems that the object doesn't carry the characteristics of class A" Show what you directly observe, i.e. the first step of the deduction chain rathwr than the last one.